# Visual studio - Angular 2 project structure

Tags: visual-studio, angular, structure

I'm using Visual studio 2015 to develop multiple angular2 single page apps. The applications share some common components (Login, header, footer etc) and also I like to have only single node_modules accessible to all the apps. The apps are in single VS project within their own directories current setup that I have:

[image]

As per the best practices what is best structure for the VS solution/project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you should consider creating ONE app but with MULTIPLE ng2 modules like DealFinderModule, JobBoardModule, SharedModule. Using modular system is considered to be the best practice and will help you achieve your goals

Comment: Thanks Mike. I've tried your suggestion and achieved what I wanted.